# Python pptx change text in textframe

Tags: text, replace, shapes, python-pptx

I have a presentation. This presentation contains a slide with a text frame.
The text is: "Tested variable_variant".

I import the presentaion and walk through the shapes of the slide.
I want to get the text of the shape. And then put in a string for the variable "variable_variant".
For example: if variable_variant = “version5” the code should change the text of the shape to “Tested version5“.
The position of the shape and the size of the text should be the same.

This is a part of my code:

> for string_to_replace in values:
> if string_to_replace in shape.text:
> text = shape.text
> text_neu = text.replace(string_to_replace, values[string_to_replace])
> text_frame = shape.text_frame
> text_frame.clear()
> p = text_frame.paragraphs[0]
> p.text = text_neu

It replaces the text correctly, but the size of the letters is different after the replacement.

I tried to get the size of the textframe and put it on the textframe after replacement.
If I try to read with font.size it gives me None back...

Comment: Ah, so here you are, Anna... :-) it seems to me you're destroying the formatting by replacing the text.

Comment: To be a little more helpful, I think you will have to pick up run 0 of paragraph 0 of the text frame's font size and then set all the runs of all the paragraphs' font sizes to that value after you've done the substitution. This assumes there is only one font size in the original for each text frame.

Answer (score -1):

Solved this for my presentations using:
def update_text(slide_number, shape_name, old_text, new_text):
# presentation = Presentation(pptx_file) is already instantiated slide = presentation.slides[slide_number - 1]
for shape in slide.shapes:
if not shape.has_text_frame:  # Check if the shape object contains a TextFrame
continue
else:
print(shape.name)  # >> Title 1, Text box 3, Arrows: right 4, Callout: circular 12 <- this is debug part, remove it when done
if shape.name == shape_name:
if shape.has_text_frame:
# my debug checks - remove when done
print("Updating old: " + shape.text)
print(shape.text_frame.text)
# print(str(shape.text_frame.text.font.name))
# Iterate through paragraphs and runs to find and replace the text preserving the format
for paragraph in shape.text_frame.paragraphs:
for run in paragraph.runs:
if old_text in run.text:
updated_text = run.text.replace(old_text, new_text)
run.text = updated_text
print("With the new: " + str(new_text))

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOv7V.png)

Comment: Usually it is better to post the code as a text with proper formatting. See the [Markdown Editing Helpt](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) for formatting options.

Comment: Please format the code in your answer as code.